# i got the error java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date null

Tags: java, date, calendar

I want the date format as yyyy-MM-dd. My code is:

```
       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
              SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
              cal.setTime(sdf.parse(row.getCell(67).toString()));
```

the value in cell is : 06/02/2020
But, I got the error as:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "null"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
```

Thanks for any help....

But, I want the date in date format as yyyy-MM-dd.

this is the complete code :

```
if(row.getCell(67).equals("null"))
                  {

                      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                      cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1988);
                      cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JUNE);
                      cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                      Date dateRepresentation = cal.getTime();
                      rfx.setRv_rc_date(dateRepresentation);
                  }
                  else
                  {

                      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
                      cal.setTime(sdf.parse(row.getCell(67).toString()));
                      System.out.println("******************************************************");
                      System.out.println(cal);
                      System.out.println("*******************************************************");

                     

                  }
```

Comment: pls check your data & debug your code, to me this look as if the `row.getCell(67).toString()` returns `null`

Comment: And where is "-" in your `sdf`?

Comment: And in addition, try to avoid the outdated datetime API from `java.util`, use `java.time` instead.

Comment: please check the answer again i just updated

Comment: i got this error : java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "30-janv.-2020"

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0):

> i got this error : java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "30-janv.-2020"

On searching this date in Google I found that it is in the `French` locale whereas you have used `Locale.ENGLISH`.

[image]

As shown below, use `Locale.FRENCH` instead to get rid of the error

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd", Locale.FRENCH);
```

**Demo:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        // Input format
        SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.FRENCH);
        Date date = inputFormat.parse("30-janv.-2020");

        // Output format
        SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        System.out.println(outputFormat.format(date));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-01-30
```

However, I recommend you stop using outdated date-time API and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) as shown below:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.FRENCH);
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("30-janv.-2020", formatter);
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-01-30
```

Note that I haven't defined any formatter for this output because [LocalDate#toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toString--) already returns a string in your required format.