# java.text.ParseException Unparseable date

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar, apache-poi

Getting parse exception when I'm applying a particular format to the date.

this is my code :

```
System.out.println("*********************1**********************");

if(row.getCell(67).toString().equals("null"))
{
    System.out.println("*********************2**********************");

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1988);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JUNE);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    Date dateRepresentation = cal.getTime();
    rfx.setRv_rc_date(dateRepresentation);
}
else
{
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
    cal.setTime(sdf.parse(row.getCell(67).toString()));
    System.out.println("******************************************************");
    System.out.println(cal);
    System.out.println("*******************************************************");
}
```

this is the error :

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "30-janv.-2020"

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Somehow related: [i got the error java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date null \[closed\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62592385/i-got-the-error-java-text-parseexception-unparseable-date-null)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse a french date (janv. is the abbrevation for janvier or in English, January), so instead of `Locale.ENGLISH` you have to use `Locale.FRENCH` like below:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.FRENCH);
Date date = sdf.parse("30-janv.-2020");
```

Please use the `java.time` api instead of `Date` or `Calendar` classes unless you have some specific reason to do it.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you want to parse a french date, so you have to use `Locale.FRENCH`

```
String dateval = row.getCell(67).toString();
SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat( "dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.FRENCH );
Date date = sdf.parse( dateval );
System.out.println(date);
```